# How does Camera addCallbackBuffer mechanism works?

Tags: android, camera, buffer, frame

Here is the explanation of addCallbackBuffer: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#addCallbackBuffer(byte[])

I couldnt understand  this mechanism and how to use it. We can add one or more buffer. Suppose that we added 10 buffer. is OnPreviewFrame method is called when 10 buffer is filled?

Suppose that a buffer is removed from the buffer queue and OnPreviewFrame is called with that buffer. When we call addCallbackBuffer method with the arrived buffer, is the buffer added to head of the queue and next OnPreviewFrame is called with that buffer?

When we call addCallbackBuffer, how can we get the timestamp of the frame?

Is there any frame drops when we call addCallbackBuffer?

Comment: In interpreting the documentation, it suggests that in your example of adding 10 buffers, each one is filled sequentially and removed from the queue (it says "queue", so FIFO). I think what you're getting at, is to know which buffer you're getting back. I haven't played with this myself, but perhaps you can provide a byte array that is too large, and pre-fill those extra bytes with some identifier?

Comment: Hi Paul, I will dig into this API as you mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

use setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer and addCallbackBuffer together.

At first, you should call [addCallbackBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#addCallbackBuffer(byte[])) before calling setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer. You can add buffer by calling addCallbackBuffer for 4-5 frames. It depends on your project. How many bytes a frame requires [expains here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#addCallbackBuffer(byte[])).

Everytime onPreviewFrame is called, buffer added by addCallbackBuffer is used. As long as there is enough buffer added by addCallbackBuffer, onPreviewFrame is called. If there is no buffer left for onPreviewFrame, frames are started to drop and onPreviewFrame is not called.

So you should keep calling addCallbackBuffer during the execution. You can call addCallbackBuffer with the byte array parameter on onPreviewFrame after you process the data. In this way, you always reuse the same buffers.

If there is a point that i missed to explain, please let me know.